# Dynamically generate table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use JQuery version 1.8.4 and jquery-ui-1.9.2

I have this array:

```
window.mapData.Layers = [{id:1,Title:water}{id:2,Title:land}{id:4,Title:data}{id:1,Title:info}]
```

I try to create table with some text and two buttons.

Each row in table have to display `title` the property of object from Layers array
and two buttons `edit` and `delete`.Each button have to sent as parameter the `id` of the property to handler when it clicked.

Here is the code:

```
(function () {
    var content = $('<table>')
    $(window.mapData.Layers).each(function (i, j) {
        content += '<tr><td>' + j.Title + '</td><td>' + $('<button/>')
    .text('Edit').onClick('eventHandler').params('j.id') +'</td>'+'<td>'+$('<button/>').text('Delete').onClick('eventHandler').params('j.id')+'</td>'+'</td></tr>'})

        $('#vectorLayerslist').append(content);
    }())
```

Here is result that I get:

```
water   [object Object] [object Object]
land    [object Object] [object Object]
data    [object Object] [object Object]
info    [object Object] [object Object]
```

But it's not works.As you can see above it's generate only text but not buttons.
Any idea why buttons not generated? If there is any more elegant way to achieve my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the table as string, then append the string once.

Make use of [jQuery's event propagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) for dynamically created elements.

```js
var Layers = [{id:1,Title:'water'},{id:2,Title:'land'},{id:4,Title:'data'},{id:5,Title:'info'}];

var vectorLayersList = $('#vectorLayerslist');

// build the table
var content = '<table>';
    content += '<thead><tr>';
    content += '<th>Title</th>';
    content += '<th colspan="2">Actions</th>';
    content += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
$.each(Layers, function () {
    // we'll store the ID in HTML5 data-attribute for later
    content += '<tr data-id="' + this.id + '">'; 
    content += '<td>' + this.Title + '</td>';
    // give classes to your buttons for later
    content += '<td><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></td>'; 
    content += '<td><button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button></td>';
    content += '</tr>';
});
content += '</tbody></table>';

// append the table once
vectorLayersList.append(content);

// attach event handlers
vectorLayersList.on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    console.log('editing ' + id);
});

vectorLayersList.on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    console.log('deleting ' + id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="vectorLayerslist"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for post.How can I add thead to the table?

Comment: @Michael Simply add it to your string. Though if you use `<thead/>`, then you'll also need a `<tbody/>`. Check edit.